# Why trust the authors of all files in the **parent** folder

Tags: visual-studio-code

Is there any reason why it (visual-studio-code) is asking to trust the **parent** folder? It's asking to trust my root `c:\` why not trust the working folder? I know I can trust my current files but if next time I check out some untrustworthy code it is automatically trusted?

My file layout structure: `c:\solution\project`
with a `.sln` file in solution and a `.csproj` file in `project`.
from `c:\solution` start `code .`

Comment: Because people tend to put all of their projects in a single "Projects" folder, rather than directly on the C drive, perhaps...?

Comment: "Is there any reason why it is asking to trust the parent folder? It's asking to trust my root c:\ why not trust the working folder?" What is "it", and what do you mean by "asking to trust"? What do you do in order to cause the problem, and what actually happens?

Comment: It == visual studio code.

Comment: how often do you have to answer this question? Once per workspace? How often do you create new workspaces?

Comment: It feels not intuitive to trust it’s parent.

Answer (score 1):

I think I ran into the same thing. When opening a folder, VS Code shows a dialog that seems to ask if you trust the parent folder.

But it's actually asking if you trust the current folder. And then it's offering the option to "Trust the parent folder", but it has an invisible checkbox, so it looks like it's mandatory.

This issue only happens with certain color themes. I use [Mariana Pro (Cool)](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=rickynormandeau.mariana-pro), I filed a [ticket](https://github.com/n0rmand0/Mariana-Pro-color-theme/issues/22) with that theme author.

---

The dialog:

[image: VS Code trust folder dialog]

The checkbox becomes visible when checked:

[image: VS Code trust folder dialog with checkbox checked]